# Error : Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) when trying to register a background task windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

When i trying to register a background task in windows phone 8.1 insted of this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff 
i got this error :

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

i use this code :

```
Dim taskBuilder As New BackgroundTaskBuilder()
taskBuilder.Name = taskName
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(New SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserPresent, False))
taskBuilder.Register()
```

Any help please ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles.aspx

Comment: have you found any solution  ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure your `taskEntryPoint` variable value matches the **Entry point:** value you have defined in **Package.appmanifest** >>> **Declarations** >>> **Background Tasks** >>> **Entry point**.

Comment: THANK YOU. Any hints on how/why I was supposed to know this?

Comment: Great answer. As an example, suppose your entry point is a class of a background task project in the same VS solution, it should be the fully qualified class name with its name space (e.g.  My_Background_Project_Name.MyBackgroundTask).  Just go to the class file to find its name and namespace.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer (for me).  I didn't pay attention to capitalization in my declaration in the Package.appmanifest.  In there I set the entry point as Projectname.ClassName and when I was SetTrigger in code, I set it as ProjectName.ClassName.

My what a difference a letter makes!

Comment: LOL! I made a similar mistake, leaving out a letter in the entry point reference in Package.appmanifest.  It's amazing how incredibly unhelpful this error message is.

Comment: I am trying below code and getting same error `BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                builder.Name = "Push Notifcation Task";
                builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(PushNotificationBackgroundTask).FullName;
                builder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());
                builder.Register();` I have added `PushNotificationBackgroundTask.cs` in shared project and in package manifest i have added it in EntryPoint

Comment: I too missed one letter which should have been uppercase. This answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, guys! FN' MSFT even didn't give any informational error message!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'd made the mistake of putting the 'Background Tasks' declaration (where I specified the Entry Point) into the appxmanifest of the BackgroundTask project itself... whereas it needs to go into the appxmanifest of the project which registers the background task, which in my case was the UI project.