# Register an in-process background task in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to register an in process background task that will enable me to process a background-event from a toast-notification action. I have created an override of the OnBackgroundActivated in my app class, but when i call register on my BackgroundTaskBuilder i get this exception:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
{
    Name = "myTask"
};
builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

I find a lot of solutions that suggests this is because the name of the entry point in Package.appxmanifest is incorrect. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753670/error-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classn), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450422/backgroundtaskbuilder-register-throws-exception), and [here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2015/02/10/Adding-a-Background-Task-to-the-Windows-Platform-Applications.aspx). But according to [this article on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task), i'm not supposed to specify the entry point when i want to perform an in-process background task:

> For in-process background activities you do not set TaskEntryPoint. Leaving it blank enables the default entry point, a new protected method on the Application object called OnBackgroundActivated().

The msdn-article states that i have to call RequestAccessAsync, but both [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700494.aspx) and intellisense indicates that it's not necessary. However, if i call RequestAccessAsync, it throws the same exception.

Comment: Your registration code is working on my side with the OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args) override implemented. Did you had more information about the missing class in the exception details? It may help... In the mean time (if not already done)you can double check the OnBackgroundActivated() prototype, try a full rebuild and/or if possible try to compile on another machine. I suspect something wrong with the SDK setup...

Comment: There is no inner exception. I just tried on another computer and it worked fine. I have tried to clean, rebuild, unload and reload, restore nuget several times. What can i do to make it work on my "main" computer?

Comment: I'm afraid that your only hope will be to reinstall the UWP SDK from the VS installer.

Comment: Reinstalling SDK did not help. Repairing visual studio did not help either.

Comment: What's the version of your windows 10 SDK?

Comment: Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.14393.33

Comment: Can you show us your Manifest ?

Comment: The Package.appxmanifest does not contain any declarations since this is only supposed to be done for out of process tasks. The file is also identical on both computers running my project, so I don't think the error lies in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the OS on the Windows Phone emulator I used. Reinstalling the SDK seems to be the proper way to solve this as Vincent suggested in his comment. Reinstalling the SDK on my computer obviously had no effect since the problem occurred after deployment to the virtual device.

By resetting the phone in the device settings on the emulator I was able to deploy and run the application successfully on the emulator again.